# ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am completely new to Handlebars.js and almost new to JavaScript itself. I'm getting this error on the console "ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined". I have already tried to put alle the references befor the "x-handlebars-templates" but it did not help.

index.tmpl.php:

```js
<html>

 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>PHP and jquery</title>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="container">
 

<h1>Search films by title:</h1>
<form id="film-selection" action="index.php" method="post">
 
 <select name="q" id="q">
  <?php
           $alphabet = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
           foreach ($alphabet as $letter) {
             echo "<option value='$letter'>$letter</option>";
           }
  ?>
 </select>
 <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>

  <?php if(isset($film)): ?>
  <ul class="film-list">
   <?php
         foreach ($film as $a) {
           echo " <li data-film_id='{$a->film_id}'> 
                     <a href='film.php?film_id={$a->film_id}'>{$a->title} </a>
                  </li>";
         }
   ?>

  </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>



<script id="film_list_template" type="text/x-handlebares-templates">
  {{#each this}}
         <li data-film_id="{{film_id}}">
            <a href="film.php?film_id={{film_id}}">{{fulName this}}</a>
         </li>
     {{/each}}

</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```js
var Film = {
 init: function(config){
  this.config = config;
  this.setupTemplates();
  this.bindEvents();

 },

 bindEvents: function(){
  this.config.letterSection.on('change', this.fetchFilm);

 },

 setupTemplates: function(){
      //The error is in this line below. 
      this.config.filmListTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.config.filmListTemplate); //here is the error
      Handlebars.registerHelper('fulName', function(film){
          return film.title;
      });
 },

 fetchFilm: function(){
   alert('Test2');
      
   var self = Film;
 
   $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: self.config.form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results){
      //console.log(results[0].title);
      self.config.filmList.append(self.config.filmListTemplate(results));

    }
   });
 }
};

Film.init({
   letterSection: $('#q'),
   form: $('#film-selection'),
   filmListTemplate: $('#film_list_template').html(),
   filmList: $('ul.film-list')
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to copy script references into head section of HTML document? Error indicates that handlebar js file is not loaded. It is eather it's not loaded at all, or not loaded at the moment you are trying to use some handlebar functions.

Comment: Yes I tried. You are right the handlebars script is not being loaded. I saw it in the network tab that it is not being loaded.

Comment: Good, glad I helped.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that i had not the file"handlebars-v2.0.0.js" in my js directory.