# Uncaught ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Hi saw that there was another post with the same title "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645823/referenceerror-handlebars-is-not-defined" as this but the problem does not look to be the same. I'm trying to build a single page app but I keep getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined" error in the console. The network tab on the console looks to show that the handlebars.min.js is being loaded.

Comment: please don't refer to external sources. instead post your code here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking handlebars before it is getting loaded. Move your script that compiles handlebars to body like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/materialize/bin/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="main-template">
    <h1>Loaded main template</h1>  
  </script>
    <button class="clear-screen">Click Me</button>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper" id="nav-color">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
          <li><a href="#!"><i class="mdi-action-home left"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="mdi-content-add left"></i>Add Card</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="mdi-navigation-close left"></i>Remove Card</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="mdi-action-stars left"></i>Get Premium</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="mdi-action-settings left"></i>Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
     <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header" id="flybuys"><span id="flybuys-text">FlyBuys</span></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><img id="barcode" src="http://www.barcodes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header" id="airpoints"><span id="airpoints-text">Airpoints</span></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><img id="barcode" src="http://www.barcodes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header" id="onecard"><span id="airpoints-text">OneCard</span></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><img id="barcode" src="http://www.barcodes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif" /></div>
    </li>
         <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header" id="summitclub"><span id="summit-text">Kathmandu Summit Club</span></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><img id="barcode" src="http://www.barcodes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif" /></div>
    </li>
         <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header" id="clubcard"><span id="new-world-text">New World ClubCard</span></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><img id="barcode" src="http://www.barcodes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif" /></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a id="btn-color" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Add More</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Get Premium</h4>
      <p>To have more than 5 card you need Premium, this gives you the ability to have unlimited card! Get it now for only $1.</p>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat ">Not now</a>
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Get Premium </a>
          </div>
  </div>

    <div class="content">
        init content
    </div>


    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/materialize/bin/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        var template = handlebars.compile( $('#main-template').html() );
        $(document).on('click','.clear-screen', function(){
            $('.content').html( template() );
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can also listen for jQuery ready

Comment: Are you checking in your fiddle link ?

Comment: Dude, it is `Handlebars.compile` not `handlebars.compile`