# Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined when using handbelar.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, jsfiddle

I am copy pasting the code from the tutorial here: https://sabe.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-handlebars-js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/requirejs@2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@4.7.7/lib/index.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const context = {
      name: "Sabe"
    };
    const template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());
    $("#template").html(template(context))
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Hello, my name is {{name}}!</p>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/pathikrit/kaj74qef/7/

Before someone marks this as a duplicate of this,
[Uncaught ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695551/uncaught-referenceerror-handlebars-is-not-defined)

I tried the answer from that and it also gives an error: https://jsfiddle.net/pathikrit/vw2ds57z/ and my code does not have the problem of wrong order of imports that that question has.

Comment: This following the actual error looking at the jsfiddle, and that is you should be going after I think, Due to which reference error is coming.

`Uncaught Error: Module name "../dist/cjs/handlebars" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: @WahabShah: Ok sure but why? I am just following the example!

Comment: That Handlebars file you are loading is not the Handlebars library, it just tries to load the module from `../dist/cjs/handlebars`, but can't. I'm not sure how you are supposed to use this file, but I would just get Handlebars from CDN JS: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js. You won't need the require library in order to use this.